# Using jQuery, how do I add and remove elements based on browser width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on something and I'm trying to add and remove elements based on the browser width. In the example that I have (https://jsfiddle.net/swpm3aL1/), I want the image to appear when browser width is 700px or lower and remove the video, and vise versa.

I have some code but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time and help!

```
if ($(window).width() > 700) {
    $('body').remove('#image');
    $('body').add('#video');

} else {
    $('body').remove('#video');
    $('body').add('#image');
}
```

Comment: On which event you have written this code? It must be written on window.onresize. Please confirm.

Comment: You're better off using CSS for this

Comment: `$('body').add('#video');` What kind of jQuery is this?

Comment: use responsive css and media queries to set `display:none` or `display:block` for elements you want to show/hide, it's more efficient and more maintainable. `@media screen and (max-width:700px) { }` etc

Comment: As Mousey suggested, this is almost certainly better solved with css `@media` rules than with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly didn't RTFM

```
if ($(window).width() > 700) {
    $('#image').hide();
    $('#video').show();

} else {
    $('#image').show();
    $('#video').hide();
}
```

The jQuery manual, or the jsFiddle manual https://jsfiddle.net/swpm3aL1/1/

If you want this on window resize

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 700) {
        $('#image').hide();
        $('#video').show();

    } else {
        $('#image').show();
        $('#video').hide();
    }
}).trigger('resize'); // <-- and trigger so it works on page load
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle onload, resize and change of orientation, then following code will be handy:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange load resize", function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 700) {
      $('#image').hide();
      $('#video').show();
  } else {
      $('#image').show();
      $('#video').hide();
  }
});
```